# How to show an image to jsp page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp

I have used ajax to pass primary key to fetch an image. Now image is in byte array and in a bean. How can i show this image to jsp page? suggest me any method that could work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the [data uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

```
 document.getElementById("imgId").src = "data:image/png;base64," + TheBase64Variable;
```

Why use an Ajax call when you can set the source directly?

```
document.getElementById("imgId").src = "foo.jsp?foo=bar";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Servlet.  Just write the bytes in the response's output stream.

JSP:

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/myServlet"/>
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(bytes);
    outputStream.flush();
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.x.y.z.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can pass image name as query string and based on image name you can write corresponding bytes in the response's output stream.